# Struts 2 Hello word

Tags: java, struts2

I'm new in struts 2 when run hello word example I get this error
HTTP Status 404 - There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name Login.
I put jsp pages in wepapp/pages folder,How can I solve that?

```
   @ResultPath(value="/")
   public class HelloController extends ActionSupport{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
    @Action(value="/Login",results={@Result(name="success",location="pages/login.jsp")})
public String execute()throws Exception
{
    return "success";
}
   }
```

web.xml

```
 <filter>
<filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
 </filter>

 <filter-mapping>
<filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

and this pom file

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
    <dependency>
<groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
<version>1.1.1</version>
 </dependency>

     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
  <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.8</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
  <artifactId>struts2-convention-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.8</version>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

 </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it,I must add HelloController class at the packaged named action ,because struts 2 Scans the annotated classes which located at the packaged named “struts, struts2, action or actions“

Answer (score 0):

You should have to call the action name in your url :

```
http://localhost:<your-port>/Login.action
```

Also change the action name to:

```
@Action(value="Login" ....
```

Comment: install Config Browser Plugin http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/config-browser-plugin.html to see what is your actions are mapped to

Answer (score 0):

**Your filter is deprecated**. From Struts 2.1.3 up, [you need to change](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/difference-between-struts-2-filterdispatcher-and-strutsprepareandexecutefilter/) from `FilterDispatcher` to `StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter`.

It would also be great to migrate to at least 2.3.16, to avoid security issues discovered and patched along the years.

2.1 is very old...